# Prove by induction that $(n+1)!>3^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\geq 4$.

Tags: solution-verification, induction

Prove that $( + 1)! > 3^n$

for  ∈ ℤ,  ≥ 4

My proof:

Let n = 4

$(4+1)!>3^4$

$120>81$

Find next term

$(n+1+1)!>3^{n+1} $

$(n+2)(n+1)!>3^{n}\times3^1$

Since, $(n+1)!>3^n$, is assumed to be true, we just have to prove:

$(n+2)>3^1$, which is true for all n≥4, thus proven by induction. Is this proof valid?

How would you prove it?

Comment: The proof is valid. You could clean up the induction step a little by saying, "Since $(n + 1)! > 3^n$, then$$(n + 2)! = (n + 2)(n + 1)! > (n + 2)3^n > 3 \cdot 3^n = 3^{n+1}."$$

Comment: Yes, that proof is valid and that is *exactly* how I would prove it.

Comment: It is valid and everyone would do it this way. But it is important to practice the including of explanations of why any sentence follows from prior ones, rather than presenting a series of separate assertions. This will help your understanding. Although it seems unnecessary in a simple problem like this, it is indipensable in more compex arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments have essentially answered the question, but I think the inductive argument could be expressed a little more clearly as follows:

> Proposition: $(n+1)!>3^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n\geq 4$.

*Proof*: It is clear that this holds when $n=4$. If we assume (for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n\geq 4$) that $(n+1)!>3^n$, then $$((n+1)+1)!=(n+2)(n+1)!>(n+2)\cdot 3^n\geq 6\cdot 3^n>3^{n+1}.$$ Since it holds for the first value ($n=4$) and if it holds for $n$, then it must also hold for $n+1$, we have established that $(n+1)!>3^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n\geq 4$.